# Can wait_event be woken up by two wake_up_interruptable from different threads?

Tags: linux, kernel

I have this problem of wake up a thread from two sources. The idea is that in the main thread, I have a function to read a sysfs entry. It is a block read. The read function is like this:

```
static bool read_wait;
static ssize_t mode_read(struct device *dev,
                                        struct device_attribute *attr,
                                    char *buf)
{
    struct st_data *st = (struct st_data *)dev_get_drvdata(dev);

    wait_event(st->pollq, read_wait);
    read_wait = false;
    init_waitqueue_head(&st->pollq);

    return snprintf(buf, 100, "%d\n", st->source);
}
```

In the interrupt handler, I have this code:

```
static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    struct st_data *st = (struct st_data *)dev_id;

    read_wait = true;
    st->source = 1;
    wake_up_interruptible(&st->pollq);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

I then have another sysfs entry that has a write function like this:

```
static ssize_t wakeup_mode_write(struct device *dev,
            struct device_attribute *attr,
            const char *buf, size_t len)
{
    struct st_data *st = (struct st_data *)dev_get_drvdata(dev);
    read_wait = true;
    st->source = 2;
    wake_up_interruptible(&st->pollq);

    return len;
}
```

The idea is while the thread is reading and waiting on the read sysfs function mode_read, there are two thread can wake it up. It could be interrupt. The interrupt can wake it up. Or there could a command from upper layer. This command will write to a sysfs entry and wake it up. 
However, I found that only the irq can wake it up. If I issue a command through sysfs entry to `wakeup_mode_write`, it does not wake it up and hanging there. Can anyone help me about it?

Below is the probe function:

```
static DEVICE_ATTR(_curr_mode,   S_IRUGO, mode_read, NULL);
static DEVICE_ATTR(_wakeup_mode, S_IWUSR, NULL, wakeup_mode_write);

static struct attribute *inv_fp_attributes[] = {
    &dev_attr__curr_mode.attr,
    &dev_attr__wakeup_mode.attr,
    NULL,
};

static struct attribute_group inv_fp_group = {
    .name   = NULL,                 /* put in device directory */
    .attrs  = inv_fp_attributes,
};

static int inv_fp_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct st_data *st;
    int error = 0;

    st = kzalloc(sizeof(struct st_data), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!st) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, st);

    st->irq = irq_of_parse_and_map(pdev->dev.of_node, 0);
    error = request_threaded_irq(st->irq, inv_irq_handler,
                   NULL,
                   IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_SHARED, "inv_fp_irq",
                   st);
    if (error) {
        goto err_class_create;
    }
    st->class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DRV_CLASS_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(st->class)) {
        error = PTR_ERR(inv_fp->class);
        goto err_class_create;
    }

    error = alloc_chrdev_region(&st->devno, 0, 1, DRV_NAME);
    if (error < 0) {
        goto err_alloc_chrdev;
    }

    st->device = device_create(st->class, NULL, st->devno,
                      NULL, "%s", DRV_NAME);

    if (IS_ERR(st->device)) {
        error = PTR_ERR(st->device);
        goto err_device_create;
    }

    cdev_init(&st->cdev, &inv_fp_fops);
    st->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;

    error = cdev_add(&st->cdev, st->devno, 1);
    if (error) {
        goto err_inv_fp_init_instance;
    }
    dev_set_drvdata(st->device, inv_fp);
    error  = sysfs_create_group(&st->device->kobj, &inv_fp_group);
    if (error < 0) {
        pr_err("add_sysfs_interfaces failed.\n");
        goto err_inv_fp_init_instance;
    }

    st->new_data = 0;
    st->enabled = 0;
    init_waitqueue_head(&st->pollq);

    st->dev = &pdev->dev;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is, if no interrupt is raised, `wakeup_mode_write()` doesn't wake up even **first call** to `mode_read()`. Am I correctly understand your case? If so, you probably use different devices. In any case, rearming waitqueue with `init_waitqueue_head` is wrong: this function is only for initialization, it shouldn't be used concurrently with other users of waitqueue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right. I tried to use wakeup_mode_wirte() to wake up first and it does not wake up the thread. Why is that? What's the meaning of "use different devices"? I remove the init_waitqueue_head in the code. It was a desperate efforts. I checked the address of data structure st. They are all the same. Does this mean I am using the same device?

Comment: I posted the probe function. Is there anything I missed here? Thanks.

Comment: Is wakeup_mode_write and mode_read has to be the same sysfs entry? I put it as two different sysfs entries. One only has write method and is using "wakeup_mode_write". The other only has read method as it is using "mode_read".

Comment: You assign different names for attributes (and access using different files). But you could check whether wakeup_mode_write() is **actually** called (by inserting `printk` statement into it).

Comment: I didn't know that they need to be in the same file. Isn't in the same driver good enough? Why interrupt handler can wake it up? I tried to combine the read and write into one file. However, the result is the same. Writing to it does not wake it up. I put printk in the write function. It shows I did write to the sysfs entry. However, the read function is not passing.

Comment: Hmm, I guess `wake_up_interruptible()` simply doesn not work for threads in *UNINTERRUPTIBLE* waiting (provided by `wait_event()`). You need to use `wake_up` for thread waited with `wait_event`. (But for threads waited with `wait_event_interruptible` can be awoken by both `wake_up` and `wake_up_interruptible`).

Comment: This works like magic. It is the problem. I changed to wait_even_interruptable and it works. Thank you very much. I had thought that this wait_event_interruptable only respond to interrupt signals.  This problem is solved.